# Firefox crash and Hard Disk usage is 100%

Tags: arch-linux, crash, segmentation-fault, core-dump

Distribution: **Arch Linux x86_64**

DE: **Xfce4**

When I using Firefox or dwb web browser, while surfing some web pages, the computer stack for a while then the browser crash.

I observed that when this problem occurs, **Hard Disk usage become 100% ,then the program crash.**

I open those programs from Terminal and I get the following:

**Firefox:**

```
$ firefox

(process:5167): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed

(firefox:5167): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_clipboard_set_with_data: assertion 'targets != NULL' failed
1434771392248   addons.update-checker   WARN    Update manifest for {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} did not contain an updates property
SystemMessageCache: initlibva info: VA-API version 0.37.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/dri/nvidia_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_35
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

**Dwb:**

```
$ dwb
No settingsfile found: Failed to open file '/home/me/.config/dwb/settings': No such file or directory
Using default values.
No keyfile found: No such file or directory
Using default values.

(dwb:5032): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid unclassed pointer in cast to 'WebKitDOMNode'

** (dwb:5032): CRITICAL **: WebKitDOMNode* webkit_dom_node_get_parent_node(WebKitDOMNode*): assertion 'WEBKIT_DOM_IS_NODE(self)' failed

(dwb:5032): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid unclassed pointer in cast to 'WebKitDOMNode'

** (dwb:5032): CRITICAL **: WebKitDOMNode* webkit_dom_node_get_parent_node(WebKitDOMNode*): assertion 'WEBKIT_DOM_IS_NODE(self)' failed

(dwb:5032): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid unclassed pointer in cast to 'WebKitDOMNode'

** (dwb:5032): CRITICAL **: WebKitDOMNode* webkit_dom_node_get_parent_node(WebKitDOMNode*): assertion 'WEBKIT_DOM_IS_NODE(self)' failed

(dwb:5032): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid uninstantiatable type '<invalid>' in cast to 'WebKitDOMNode'

** (dwb:5032): CRITICAL **: WebKitDOMNode* webkit_dom_node_get_parent_node(WebKitDOMNode*): assertion 'WEBKIT_DOM_IS_NODE(self)' failed
Received SIGSEGV, trying to clean up.

Last 32 stack frames:

 32: dwb() [0x411bf3]
 31: dwb() [0x43057f]
 30: /usr/lib/libc.so.6(+0x335b0) [0x7faca9d945b0]
 29: /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_type_check_instance_cast+0x4b) [0x7facab5e952b]
 28: dwb() [0x41446f]
 27: dwb() [0x414722]
 26: /usr/lib/libffi.so.6(ffi_call_unix64+0x4c) [0x7faca29071f0]
 25: /usr/lib/libffi.so.6(ffi_call+0x2f8) [0x7faca2906c58]
 24: /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_cclosure_marshal_generic+0x1e4) [0x7facab5c6b04]
 23: /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_closure_invoke+0x145) [0x7facab5c62f5]
 22: /usr/lib/libwebkitgtk-1.0.so.0(+0x13eeb20) [0x7facae2e3b20]
 21: /usr/lib/libwebkitgtk-1.0.so.0(+0x7c03df) [0x7facad6b53df]
 20: /usr/lib/libwebkitgtk-1.0.so.0(+0x7c0879) [0x7facad6b5879]
 19: /usr/lib/libwebkitgtk-1.0.so.0(+0x7ba3c7) [0x7facad6af3c7]
 18: /usr/lib/libwebkitgtk-1.0.so.0(+0x7bbf90) [0x7facad6b0f90]
 17: /usr/lib/libwebkitgtk-1.0.so.0(+0x7d4ac5) [0x7facad6c9ac5]
 16: /usr/lib/libwebkitgtk-1.0.so.0(+0x7d5b32) [0x7facad6cab32]
 15: /usr/lib/libwebkitgtk-1.0.so.0(+0x977335) [0x7facad86c335]
 14: /usr/lib/libwebkitgtk-1.0.so.0(+0x96e7bd) [0x7facad8637bd]
 13: /usr/lib/libwebkitgtk-1.0.so.0(+0xbd5fd7) [0x7facadacafd7]
 12: /usr/lib/libwebkitgtk-1.0.so.0(+0xbdbf7b) [0x7facadad0f7b]
 11: /usr/lib/libwebkitgtk-1.0.so.0(+0xbdc039) [0x7facadad1039]
 10: /usr/lib/libwebkitgtk-1.0.so.0(+0x563479) [0x7facad458479]
  9: /usr/lib/libwebkitgtk-1.0.so.0(+0x584452) [0x7facad479452]
  8: /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0(+0x4a3a3) [0x7facaa9d93a3]
  7: /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_main_context_dispatch+0x15d) [0x7facaa9d890d]
  6: /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0(+0x49ce0) [0x7facaa9d8ce0]
  5: /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_main_context_iteration+0x2c) [0x7facaa9d8d8c]
  4: /usr/lib/libgio-2.0.so.0(g_application_run+0x20c) [0x7facab8b047c]
  3: dwb() [0x43c7a4]
  2: /usr/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0) [0x7faca9d81790]
  1: dwb() [0x411ce9]
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Use `find -size +5000`  to find the big files...

Comment: Why, @BasileStarynkevitch what is the benefit of doing that?.

Answer (score 0):

Many programs including firefox write all kinds of files (caches, config files, etc) in the user's home directory or a subdirectory of it and if the partition fills up they crash because such writes fail.

2 options:

1. delete some stuff from your homedir to make more room (you want at
   least some 10s of MB free for firefox alone, probably more for the
   others, I'd go for several GBs to stay on the safe side)
2. if the program uses a subdirectory for its files (like ~/.mozilla
   for    firefox & friends) and you have enough free room on some
   other    partition you could create such dir on the other partition
   and    symlink it in your homedir - but it's not trivial to maintain
   such    scheme

Even after getting enough room the programs may continue to crash due to previously written partial/incomplete files. In such case you'll have to either:

- prograssively cleanup each offending file until the program is happy
  (very tedious)
- rename those directories, allow the program to start with default
  configs (it will re-create the dir) then manually try to recover
  various configs and customisations from the renamed dir or some
  backup if you have one (for firefox, for example, using recipes like
  this one:
  https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/recovering-important-data-from-an-old-profile).
  Not all of them may be recoverable, YMMV.

In general it's a good idea to periodically check the free space in your homedir and cleanup when needed to avoid such cases in the future.

Comment: I think that is not the problem, because the partition size of `/` which including `/home` is 60GB and I only used about 28GB of it.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the `hard disk usage 100% ` part, my answer doesn't apply then. If you refer to a hard disk activity peak - it could very well be an *effect* of the crash - dumping the process corefile which can be fairly big thus taking a while to write.